# Suggestion of leveling build for Barbarians

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

Can anybody suggests me a good leveling build for my Barbarian? I am currently at level 35 using 2 one handed weapons. I would like a build capable of tons of damage. I just killed Diablo in normal difficulty.

Comment: It is very difficult to offer you suggestions because we don't know your playstyle, what your current gear is, etc. It is fair simple to offer you a general indication (for example focusing on strength/vitality gear with other stats, using higher damaging weapons than what you have, etc.) but this question is far too broad to cover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a selection of barbarian builds here: http://www.ign.com/wikis/diablo-3/Barbarian_Builds?objectid=120933

Check out and experiment what suits you best.

Filter them according to your level, and your play style.